# jQuery Validate: Checked *or* Filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

[`required( dependency-expression )`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression)

They give an example of `required: "#other:checked"` but I want my field to be required if the `#other` field is either `:checked` *or* `:filled` (I don't know whether it will be a checkbox, radio button, or textbox beforehand).  How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it checks length of the jquery element matching this selector, this should work:

```
required: "#other:checked, #other:filled"
```

This is the code that actually uses that string:

```
return !!$(param, element.form).length;
```

An easier way to think about it: if `$(yourString, yourForm).length > 0`, it will be a required field.

Comment: That's kind of weird. Why do they use double negation instead of `> 0`? Is it faster?

Comment: @Mark - Not sure, style choice I guess, might be faster in some browsers/tracing engines.